# How to use docker passed environment variable in log4j2?

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, log4j2

I have a spring-boot based application that uses `log4j2.xml` in a dockerized environment.

When I launch the docker I pass `-e "LOG4J_PATH=/tmp/app.log"` to specify where the logs should go to.

Next, in the `log4j2.xml` I use `fileName="${env:LOG4J_PATH}"` but this doesn't work. I searched the web for hours and thus tried double $ and tried `sys` instead of `env`... nothing.

This `System.getenv("LOG4J_PATH")` and `(new EnvironmentLookup()).lookup("LOG4J_PATH")` work fine, so I know that the variable is being passed to the running image ok, but from some reason the log4j doesn't seem to pick it up.

If I run this not via a docker and set the `LOG4J_PATH` environment variable in my `.bash_profile` it works fine so this is something between docker and log4j.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe the variable is being set in/with a user different than the one executing your application within the container?

Comment: note the the environment variable is correctly retrieved by the code, so I don't see how this could be a user issue

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue ? I am stuck with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change the key value structure a bit for your passed environment variable.  Can you try

```
docker run -e LOG4J_PATH='/tmp/app.log'
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help